# stat systecall in linux returning error

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, redhat, system-calls

I am using RHEL 4

i am using syscall stat as follows:-

```
if (stat ("file",&stat_obj)){

     if (errno == ENOENT){
        printf("File not found");
     }else{
        printf("Unexpected error occured %d ",errno);
     }
}
```

sometimes i get error message as ""Unexpected error occured 0"

That means i get error as "0" . i checked file permissions that are ok

what does that mean? I am not able to understand why sometimes this is happening ?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it give you any meaningful error message if you call it like this?

```
   if (stat("file", &stat_obj) == -1) {
       perror("stat");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a signal handler in your program?  If so, and it may affect `errno`, then make sure that it saves `errno` on entry and restores it to its original value before returning.

Also ensure that you `#include <errno.h>`, and are not declaring `errno` yourself, especially if your program is multithreaded.  `errno` is a per-thread variable so if you declare it as a global you can get the wrong one.  (On some platforms you sometimes also need a special compilation flag like `-D_TS_ERRNO` for thread-safe errno, but no such flag is needed on Linux.)

Comment: All good suggestions and probably the best that can be done in the absence of more information.